# Fix Angular 4 error with returning Observable of string array

Tags: angular, typescript

> Type 'Observable<{ "aa": any; "dd": any; "cc": any; }>' is not
>   assignable to type 'Observable'.

How can I fix this error in Angular 4? Unsure about syntax.

```
public search2(): Observable<string[]> {
        return Observable.of(
            {
                "aa","dd", "cc"
            }
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning an object {}, not an array []:

```
public search2(): Observable<string[]> {
    return Observable.of(['aa','dd', 'cc']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you expect an array, you return an object.

```
public search2(): Observable<string[]> {
    return Observable.of(['aa', 'dd', 'cc']);
}
```